# Containers Automáticos no Docker após RUN no Dockerfile

Tags: docker

Uma Dúvida sobre o dockerfile:

Depois que eu executo o build ele cria alguns containers com tag < none >, isso é normal? Não deveria criar somente o php?

```
FROM php:7.2-apache

RUN apt-get update && \
      apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
      apt-utils \
      curl \
      libmemcached-dev \
      libz-dev \
      libpq-dev \
      libjpeg-dev \
      libpng-dev \
      libfreetype6-dev \
      libssl-dev \
      libmcrypt-dev\
      libpq-dev \
      mysql-client

RUN a2enmod rewrite

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql

# COPY 000-default.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

# install GD

RUN docker-php-ext-install gd && \
      docker-php-ext-configure gd \
      --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/lib \
      --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/freetype2 && \
      docker-php-ext-install gd
```

Lista de containers criados:

```
❯ docker images -a
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED              SIZE
<none>              <none>              1ddab69ed614        15 seconds ago       463MB
<none>              <none>              6de0de8461cd        About a minute ago   378MB
php                 7.2-apache          1d7b7e0dfca8        2 days ago           378MB
```

Se eu rodar apenas docker images, aparece só o php, mas eu não consigo remover esses containers < none >, pois parece que estão ligados ao php.

Valeu

Comment: `docker images -a` >> Show all images (default hides intermediate images). Pelo que vi são imagens intermediárias criadas no momento do build.

Comment: Sim isso eu sei, o que quero saber é se é normal ele criar duas imagens < none >.. porque se eu rodar só um docker pull php7.2-apache ele cria só o php sem containers extras.

Comment: No build se você usar o `--rm` ele não vai criar isso. Agora essa quantidade pode ser algo relacionado aos *layers* da sua imagem. Vou fazer uns testes pra te confirmar :)

Comment: Tenta dar um `docker history php:7.2-apache` e adiciona a saída, para ver se bate a quantidade de *layers*

Comment: E dá uma [lida nesse artigo](http://www.projectatomic.io/blog/2015/07/what-are-docker-none-none-images/), vai ajudar a esclarecer um pouco

Comment: Pelo que li, essas imagens < none > são partes do container criado, só achei estranho que quando uso o docker pull php7.2-apache não são criadas essas < none > só quando eu uso o dockerfile com comandos RUN para executar alguma instrução. Será que para cada RUN que instala alguma coisa é criado um container < none >??

Comment: Então, como você fez o build na sua máquina cada camada que ele gera ele vai salvando aí, quando faz o pull você só baixa a imagem enxuta. Por isso as recomendações sobre escrever Dockerfiles enxutos, pra não gerar tantas camadas.

Comment: Complementando: o registry do docker hub deve gerenciar essa questão das images <none>, pra quando fizer o pull baixar só o imagem final.

Comment: Tentou remover usando o comando do artigo? (`docker rmi $(docker images -f "dangling=true" -q)`)

Comment: não removi porque só aparece no docker images -a

Answer (score 0):

isso é normal,  a primeira coluna de none esta falando que ao tem um repositório que quer dizer que você criou (build) mas não associou ao repositório do Docker Hub por exemplo, a segunda coluna foi que você não passou um valor de tag para identificar a imagem por isso ficou none.

Eu diria que você só rodou o comando `docker build .`

tem como passar os valores exemplo como passar uma tag

```
docker buil . -t meudiretorio/minhaimagem:1.1
```

link da documentação

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/